# Setting DateTime as a SqlDataSource parameter for Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

Hey I would like to display certain data with my stored procedure for the last 30 days. here is what I have done (aspx.cs file):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)     
        {
          DateTime toDate, fromDate;
          toDate = DateTime.Now;

          fromDate = toDate.Subtract(new TimeSpan(31, 0, 0, 0));

          SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("fromDate", DbType.DateTime, fromDate.ToString());
          SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("toDate", DbType.DateTime, toDate.ToString());                    

    }
```

here is my aspx file

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="232px" DataKeyNames="CustomerId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CreationDate" HeaderText="CreationDate" SortExpression="CreationDate" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <br />
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SSEnewConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="procCustomer_SelectbyCreationDate" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter DbType="DateTime" Name="fromDate" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="DateTime" Name="toDate" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </form>
```

when I test this my screen comes up blank (other than the masterpage elements) and no errors. any ideas?

Comment: well do you have any data there ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Even though an earlier version of this answer was accepted, it looks like I had misunderstood the parameter type used. The [web controls `ParameterCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) looks somewhat awful.

I would suggest converting date values to a SQL format (much as that pains me, frankly - string conversions should be avoided as far as possible). For example:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("fromDate", DbType.DateTime,
    fromDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("toDate", DbType.DateTime,
    toDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

(Change to `yyyy-MM-dd` for date-only types.)

I haven't used `SqlDataSource` myself, but it also *looks* like you're introducing the parameters twice - once in the markup, and once in the code. Given that you don't have the values in the markup (including in bindings), you may want to remove them from there - but I could be wrong on that front.

If your query isn't doing what you expect, you should check your database logs (or whatever tool is appropriate) to check what *actual* query is executing.

Comment: If i remove the toString() i get following error "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection.Add(string, System.Data.DbType, string)' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: also, removing the parameters from the aspx file seemed to solve the problem... at least I get some data on the screen now. I had to use the toString() conversion though...

Comment: I have the exact same problem. The .Add method only allows for strings and in my case it causes an error in the SQL. Not really sure how to proceed.

Comment: @carny666: No, it really doesn't only allow for strings. I suggest you ask a new question with appropriate details.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sure.. but I'd ask the EXACT same question but state that the .Add method will only allow me to use a string regardless of what type I chose, furthermore the .DefaultValue will only accept a string as an argument. In my case, converting my DateTime to a string to accommodate these methods causes an SQL error.. "ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number"

Comment: @carny666: What do you mean by "will only allow me to use a string"? Where, exactly, and what error do you get otherwise? And what is the type of your data source here? (Note that this question is about SqlDataSource...)

Comment: @JonSkeet
 dsLadleStatus.SelectParameters["SHIFT_ST_EST"].DefaultValue = shiftd;


shiftd must be of typestring...


dsLadleStatus.SelectParameters.Add("SHIFT_ST_EST", TypeCode.DateTime, shiftd);


Again... shiftd must be of typestring...

Comment: @carny666: Right, yes, the third parameter is of type `string`. (It wasn't clear to me what you meant before.) I have to admit, when I wrote this answer (a long time ago now) I suspect I was getting confused with `SqlDbParameter`. This looks like a thoroughly awful API - I'll edit with some suggestions though.

Comment: If `yyyy-MM-dd` has issues since the date format on the server is YDM, then try `yyyyMMdd` instead.