# Using Calendar1_SelectionChanged to create SqlParameter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having trouble getting my SqlParameter to work in my SqlDataSource select command. I'm trying to run a query when a new calendar date on a calendar control is selected to filter the query by the date selected. Here's what I have on the C# end:

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlParameter para1 = new SqlParameter("@mydate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    para1.Value = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(para1);
}
```

I /almost/ found what I need via this thread:
[How can I set the sqldatasource parameter's value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988614/how-can-i-set-the-sqldatasource-parameters-value)

but the solution offered by the top answer gives me the following error for the SelectParameters.Add line:
"The best overloaded match ... has some invalid arguments."

How can I fix this error and get the parameter to work in my select query?

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly try `SqlDbType.DateTime2`

Comment: @jordanhill123 Thanks for the idea; sadly, nothing changed.

Comment: What's the value for `Calendar1.SelectedDate` when this event fires?

Comment: When the page loads the calendar is set to today's date in this format: 3/6/2013 12:00:00 AM

Comment: Might sound silly, but can you confirm that `Calendar1.SelectedDate` is returning a `DateTime` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comment in regards to Jon Skeet's answer  on this link:
[Setting DateTime as a SqlDataSource parameter for Gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787303/setting-datetime-as-a-sqldatasource-parameter-for-gridview), try changing this line to

```
para1.Value = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString();
```

and see if that works.

**Edit** 
Per comment from jadarnel27, try the following:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@mydate", SqlDbType.DateTime, Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString());
```

As  `SQLParameter.Value` is of type `object`, the overload may be doing some validation on the `Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString()` to match with the `SQLDbType`

Comment: As much as I hate to even contemplate going against Jon Skeet... I cannot see the logic in turning a date object into a string representation.  There's just too much to go wrong when converting back to a date object

Comment: @freefaller Jon Skeet is saying *not* to convert from DateTime to string in the linked answer (so agreeing with what you say).  jordanhill123 here is referring to the comments by the OP of the other question below Skeet's answer that say they had to convert to string, because the DateTime wasn't valid as a parameter to the method he was using.

Comment: @freefaller I don't see the logic either but not sure where else its going wrong. It worked for the OP but I don't like it either...is it possibly something with its use in asp.net or maybe the specific calendar implementation? Just wanted to test to see if it works

Comment: And the OP here might be better off using the overload that Jon used in the linked question: `SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@mydate", SqlDbType.DateTime, Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString());`

Comment: Fair enough guys (@jadarnel27) - didn't quite follow exactly what was going on.  my only guess is that this calendar control isn't returning a .net standard DateTime object

Comment: @jadarnel27 do you think the overload should make difference? It's possible it does some validation since SQLParameter.Value is of type object

Comment: @jordanhill123 Indeed, that should work perfectly.  I posted another answer with a different way of doing it as well.  The error is happening because he's passing an object of type `SqlParamter`, when the Add method only accepts an object of type `Parameter`.  This method bypasses that problem by using a different overload.  My method just initiliazes the para1 variable as the proper type of object.

Comment: @jadarnel27 Agreed either way will work. Its found in `System.Web.UI.WebControls` and not `System.Data.SqlClient` where `SQLParameter` class is found

Comment: At first, neither your solution nor @jadarnel27 worked. It brought up the same invalid argument error when instantiating the new parameter object. However, I visited the link you provided in this answer and found that they used DbType.DateTime instead of SqlDbType.DateTime and that eliminated the error. Thanks!